# Spark UDF with nested structure as input parameter

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to operate on a `df` with the following data:

```
+---+----------------------------------------------------+
|ka |readingsWFreq                                       |
+---+----------------------------------------------------+
|列  |[[[列,つ],220], [[列,れっ],353], [[列,れつ],47074]]   |
|制  |[[[制,せい],235579]]                                |
```

And the following structure:

```
root
 |-- ka: string (nullable = true)
 |-- readingsWFreq: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- furigana: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Occ: long (nullable = true)
```

My goal is to split `readingsWFreq`'s values into three different columns. For that purpose I've tried to use `udf`s as follows:

```
val uExtractK = udf((kWFreq:Seq[((String, String), Long)]) => kWFreq.map(_._1._1))
val uExtractR = udf((kWFreq:Seq[((String, String), Long)]) => kWFreq.map(_._1._2))
val uExtractN = udf((kWFreq:Seq[((String, String), Long)]) => kWFreq.map(_._2)

val df2 = df.withColumn("K", uExtractK('readingsWFreq))
            .withColumn("R", uExtractR('readingsWFreq))
            .withColumn("N", uExtractN('readingsWFreq))
            .drop('readingsWFreq)
```

However, I'm getting an exception related to the input parameter of the `udf`s:

```
[error] (run-main-0) org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve
'UDF(readingsWFreq)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires
 array<struct<_1:struct<_1:string,_2:string>,_2:bigint>> type, however, 
'`readingsWFreq`' is of
 array<struct<furigana:struct<_1:string,_2:string>,Occ:bigint>> type.;;
```

My question is, **how can I manipulate the dataframe so that it results in the following?**

```
+---+----------------------------------------------------+
|ka |K            |R               |N                    |
+---+----------------------------------------------------+
|列  |[列, 列, 列] | [つ, れっ, れつ] | [220, 353, 47074]   |
|制  |[制]        | [せい]          | [235579]            |
```

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45080913/using-spark-udfs-with-struct-sequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `explode` the outer `array` at first and get each value and again `group` later and collect as a list with `collect_list`.

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("readingsWFreq", explode($"readingsWFreq"))

df1.select("ka", "readingsWFreq.furigana.*", "readingsWFreq.Occ")
    .groupBy("ka").agg(collect_list("_1").as("K"),
                  collect_list("_2").as("R"),
                  collect_list("Occ").as("N")
     )
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: are you sure the ordering is maintained? AFAIK you cannot rely on this in spark in general

Comment: Yeah, the ordering is not guaranteed, but the there hasn't mention about the order in question.

Comment: You could use [posexplode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@posexplode(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) instead to have an explicit ordering.

Answer (score 7):

**Dataframe API approach:**

You don't need an UDF for that, just do :

```
df.select(
  $"readingsWFreq.furigana._1".as("K"),
  $"readingsWFreq.furigana._2".as("R"),
  $"i.Occ".as("N")
)
```

The trick here is that `.` on columns of type `array` also acts as a mapping/projection operator. On columns of type `struct` this operator is for selecting an element.

**UDF-approach**

You cannot pass tuples into UDFs, rather you need to pass them as `Row`s, see e.g. [Using Spark UDFs with struct sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45080913/using-spark-udfs-with-struct-sequences)

In your case you have nested tuples, therefore you need to decompose the row twice:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row


val uExtractK = udf((kWFreq:Seq[Row]) => kWFreq.map(r => r.getAs[Row](0).getAs[String](0)))
val uExtractR = udf((kWFreq:Seq[Row]) => kWFreq.map(r => r.getAs[Row](0).getAs[String](1)))
val uExtractN = udf((kWFreq:Seq[Row]) => kWFreq.map(r => r.getAs[Long](1)))
```

Or with pattern-matching on `Row`:

```
val uExtractK = udf((kWFreq:Seq[Row]) => kWFreq.map{case Row(kr:Row,n:Long) => kr match {case Row(k:String,r:String) => k}})
val uExtractR = udf((kWFreq:Seq[Row]) => kWFreq.map{case Row(kr:Row,n:Long) => kr match {case Row(k:String,r:String) => r}})
val uExtractN = udf((kWFreq:Seq[Row]) => kWFreq.map{case Row(kr:Row,n:Long) =>  n})
```