# Casting an array of Doubles to String in spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying read data from a JSON which has an array having lat, long values something like [48.597315,-43.206085] and I want to parse them in spark sql as a single string. is there a way I can do that?

my JSON input will look something like below.

```
{"id":"11700","position":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[48.597315,-43.206085]}
```

I'm trying to push this to a rdbms store and when I'm trying to cast position.coordinates to string it's giving me

```
Can't get JDBC type for array<string>
```

as the destination datatype is nvarchar. any kind help is appreciated.!

Comment: I assume that you will get an answer much faster if you actually provide an [mcve] that shows clearly what the problem is. Currently, it's a bit too short...

Comment: updated the question. @AndreyTyukin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read your json file into a DataFrame, then 1) use `concat_ws` to stringify your lat/lon array into a single column, and 2) use `struct` to re-assemble the `position` struct-type column as follows:

```
// jsonfile:
// {"id":"11700","position":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[48.597315,-43.206085]}}

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = spark.read.json("/path/to/jsonfile")

// printSchema:
// root
//  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- position: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
//  |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)

df.withColumn("coordinates", concat_ws(",", $"position.coordinates")).
  select($"id", struct($"coordinates", $"position.type").as("position")).
  show(false)
// +-----+----------------------------+
// |id   |position                    |
// +-----+----------------------------+
// |11700|[48.597315,-43.206085,Point]|
// +-----+----------------------------+

// printSchema:
// root
//  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- position: struct (nullable = false)
//  |    |-- coordinates: string (nullable = false)
//  |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
```

[UPDATE]

Using Spark SQL:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("position_table")

spark.sql("""
    select id, concat_ws(',', position.coordinates) as position_coordinates
    from position_table
  """).
  show(false)
//+-----+--------------------+
//|id   |position_coordinates|
//+-----+--------------------+
//|11700|48.597315,-43.206085|
//|11800|49.611254,-43.90223 |
//+-----+--------------------+
```

Comment: I already tried that and I'm getting this error:
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get JDBC type for array<string>

I'm looking to convert this whole array into a string but it seems like it's converting to array of strings.

Comment: From what command did you get the `array<string>` error?  As shown in the sample code, the array type should no longer exist after the transformation on `position` using `concat_ws` and `struct`.

Comment: I have to move only coordinates field to my rdbms store. So I'm not sure if I have to use struct. but I tried that too still giving the same error.

Comment: I'm doing in sql api and my query looks like below. `select id, concat_ws(',',position.coordinates) as positioncoordinates from myView` and the whole stack trace for the error is `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get JDBC type for array<string>
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$getJdbcType$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:172)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$getJdbcType$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:172)`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to replicate the said problem (see expanded answer).

Comment: Hmm issue is on my end. thanks for the solution.! would you mind to tell me on how to parse if I have anything like `[{"lcid":1025,"value":"test"},{"lcid":5778,"value":"test2","extendedvalue":"test4"}]` to string.

Comment: Glad that you sorted it out.  Instead of extending this comment thread, I would suggest that you formulate it as a separate question along with clear requirement and expected sample output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172916/discussion-between-game-changer-and-leo-c).

Comment: Apologies for the late response.  Noticed someone responded to your new question with a similar SO link, which seems to answer your question spot-on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to transform the given column into a string before loading it into the target datasource. For example, the following code creates a new column `position.coordinates` with value as joined string of given arrays of double, by using Array's toString and removing the brackets afterward.

```
df.withColumn("position.coordinates", regexp_replace($"position.coordinates".cast("string"), "\\[|\\]", ""))
```

Alternatively, you can use UDF to do create a custom transformation function on `Row` objects. That way you can maintain the nested structure of the column. The following source (answer number 2) can give you some idea how to take up UDF for your case: [Spark UDF with nested structure as input parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49569506/spark-udf-with-nested-structure-as-input-parameter).